# how to create ssl template using ml-gradle?

Tags: ssl, gradle, marklogic, ml-gradle

How to configure gradle.properties for adding SSL templates config ? Also, I'd like to add SSL to the REST App Server.

I have looked into https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/Property-reference but couldn't find out from the README too. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/tree/master/examples/ssl-project for an example of how to set this up. This shows both a certificate template being created and used by a REST API server, and then modules being loaded via HTTPS and that same REST API server.